# Attempted to encrypt my phone and now it's rejecting my password

Tags: encryption

I attempted to encrypt my moto g4 while it was plugged into my laptop. Instead of showing the animation that it should play, it briefly showed the start of the animation and went to the main boot screen. After a few minutes it booted into the please enter your password screen. I entered my device pin and my google password, and it rejected both of them. Sometimes it tells you to turn the device off and on to start android, but it doesn't do anything. It said it would wipe after 8 more failed attempts, but now it's at negative 45. Is there any way to do a total factory reset?

Comment: Did you try the  hard reset  method?

Answer (score 0):

You can format your phone with the built in recovery menu:

1. First you have to turn off your phone.
2. So, press and hold the power button for a few moments or press the power key once and select Power Off.
3. Then, just wait while the shut down process is completed.
4. Next, start pressing and holding the Volume Down button for about 2 or 3 seconds.
5. While still pressing the Volume Down button, press the Power key and release.
6. From the menu that will be displayed, choose the Recovery option (navigate through Volume Up and Down buttons).
7. Press the Power key once to select your option.
8. When the Android logo is displayed, press the Volume Up key for a few moments.
9. While still holding this key, press the Power button and release.
10. Recovery mode should be now displayed on your Motorola Moto G4.
11. If you can’t manage it from your first attempt, don’t panic; you might have to try this method several times until you succeed in accessing the recovery mode menu.